# How do I lock when the ideal scope of the lock object is known only at runtime?

Tags: c#, locking

The requirement is fairly straightforward: I want to make sure multiple threads aren't modifying an object at the same time. The tricky part is that the object is coming from a factory whose implementation is unknown until runtime. It may return a singleton, may create a new instance each time, or may have a pool of shared instances.

```
var thing = factory.Get(...);
lock (???) {
    // modify thing
}
```

I understand it's not safe to lock on a publicly visible object that other code could potentially lock on, thus creating a possibility for deadlocks. In other words, I shouldn't `lock (thing)`. But ideally I want to lock on *something* with the same, known-only-at-runtime scope of `thing`.

One potential solution I came up with is to use a `ConcurrentDictionary` of objects keyed by `thing`'s hash code:

```
private static ConcurrentDictionary<int, object> _thingLocks =
    new ConcurrentDictionary<int, object>();

...

var thing = factory.Get(...);
var thingLock = _thingLocks.GetOrAdd(thing.GetHashCode(), new object())

lock (thingLock) {
    // modify thing
}
```

Intuitively I think this should work, because a) the locks themselves are private so nothing external could also be locking on them, and b) lock instances are *highly likely* * to be 1-to-1 with `thing` instances. But since this sort of code is very difficult to test, I wanted to ask: is this a correct and appropriate solution? Is there a better/preferred method of locking on a scope that is known only at runtime?

* - As noted in the comments, that's not guaranteed, but in the unlikely event of a collision it just means 2 `thing`s can't be modified at the same time, which is less than ideal but perfectly safe.

Comment: Presumably thing is not a value type otherwise you are unable to lock on it. Also you want to lock on the identity of thing, not just same object based on equality of things. In that case another option is using ConditionalWeakTable with thing as a key. This has the advantage of holding a weak reference to the things and will automatically remove the entry when thing is garbage collected.

Comment: Sounds like it should be the responsibility of the objects that the factory is creating to ensure that they're usable from multiple threads.   Or, if that isn't feasible, to limit how the objects can be constructed so that you *can* guarantee whether the factory is always returning the same item or a different item, or barring that, that it's acceptable to synchronize access to any one of the items, rather than only synchronize access to individual instances.

Comment: You cannot rely on the hash code of an object to be unique.

Comment: @Servy if all `thing`s are the same type AND it's a reference type AND I know that `GetHashCode` hasn't been overridden, then can't I assume hash codes are unique? All safe assumptions in this case. Oh...and that there aren't more than `int.MaxValue` instances hanging around. I could even key the dictionary by `thing` rather than `thing.GetHashCode()` if that's any better, although I think it's effectively the same.

Comment: @ToddMenier - even the object.GetHashCode doesn't guarantee uniqueness: "**different (unequal) objects can have identical hash codes**" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @hatchet Right you are. I actually looked at that page earlier and must have skimmed through it too quickly...thanks!

Comment: I still wonder if keying the dictionary on `thing` itself rather than its hash code is any better. Practically speaking it doesn't really matter. In the highly unlikely event of a collision, I'd just be over-locking, which is better than under-locking. Even a singleton lock, though not ideal, is _probably_ acceptable here. A lock that is _highly likely_ to be unique per `thing` is obviously much better.

Comment: @ToddMenier The issue with using thing as a dictionary key is that putting it in the dictionary will create a reference that keeps it alive. If the things are intended to be transient this will effectively create a memory leak unless there is some other mechanism to clean up the "dead" keys. This is why ConditionalWeakTable is useful. It uses weak references to keys so there is no need for a separate clean up activity.

Comment: @mikez That sounds like an interesting approach. Could you post the implementation as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you've got a situation where you want some additional data (a lock object) for each instance of class but you don't have control over the implementation or their lifetime. If you could change the implementation you could easily add the lock object inside the class to do whatever it is you want. This suggests a lookup based on the identity of the object, like Dictionary (or related classes like ConcurrentDictionary). This has the problem that you then have to manage the clean up of the dictionary because putting objects as keys creates references to them inside the dictionary. We want something to cleanup the values when the keys are no longer referenced. Enter [ConditionalWeakTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757(v=vs.110).aspx). It works kind of like a dictionary lookup on the identity of the key, but keeps a weak reference to it. Note that it does not use the virtual GetHashCode or Equals in its implementation. It always does reference comparisons. Also ConditionalWeakTable is already designed to be thread-safe so it pretty easy to use in place of ConcurrentDictionary:

```
class Thing
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

abstract class ThingFactory
{
    public abstract Thing GetOrCreate(string key);
}

class ThingManager
{
    private readonly ConditionalWeakTable<Thing, object> _locks;
    private readonly ThingFactory _factory;

    public ThingManager(ThingFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        _locks = new ConditionalWeakTable<Thing, object>();
    }

    public int Increment(string key,  int incr)
    {
        var thing = _factory.GetOrCreate(key);
        var thingLock = _locks.GetOrCreateValue(thing);

        lock (thingLock)
        {
            int newValue = thing.Value + incr;
            thing.Value = newValue;
            return newValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is _perfect_. Thank you.